# i have an issue with elastic search, while runnung on ubuntu. How to solve this?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

derr:~$ sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

### derr:~$ journalctl -xe
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
Pass -q to turn off this notice.
Jun 09 11:39:30 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/113930.540403:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:39:57 QB-IPL-2673 pkexec[251615]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Jun 09 11:40:56 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114056.881327:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:41:20 QB-IPL-2673 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2219]: (II) event6  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input even>
Jun 09 11:41:56 QB-IPL-2673 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2219]: (II) event6  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input even>
Jun 09 11:42:19 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114218.972986:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:42:30 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114230.193092:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:42:59 QB-IPL-2673 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2219]: (II) event6  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input even>
Jun 09 11:43:05 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114305.484786:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:43:18 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114318.605704:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:45:02 QB-IPL-2673 intellij-idea-community_intellij-idea-community.desktop[247143]: 2023-06-09 11:45:02,374 [2517017]   WARN - #c.i.>
Jun 09 11:46:45 QB-IPL-2673 intellij-idea-community_intellij-idea-community.desktop[247143]: 2023-06-09 11:46:45,572 [2620215]   WARN - #c.i.>
Jun 09 11:47:36 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [3756:252836:0609/114736.036473:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(670)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin >
Jun 09 11:47:36 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: ----- Certificate i=0 (CN=*.g.doubleclick.net) -----
Jun 09 11:47:36 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: ERROR: No matching issuer found
Jun 09 11:47:36 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114736.036750:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:47:36 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114736.113893:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:47:36 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Jun 09 11:47:36 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114736.199462:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:47:36 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: [5037:5041:0609/114736.277501:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(982)] handshake failed; returned>
Jun 09 11:47:38 QB-IPL-2673 gnome-shell[3762]: Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse processor information from /proc/cpuinfo
Jun 09 11:51:14 QB-IPL-2673 systemd[2131]: Starting snapd user session agent...
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

### -- A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution.

### -- The job identifier is 13742.
Jun 09 11:51:16 QB-IPL-2673 systemd[2131]: Started snapd user session agent.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

### -- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.

-- The job identifier is 13742.

i want to solve this issue

Comment: What is the question here, explain in more details